# How can we remove unwanted data from Databricks cluster after filtering required data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, amazon-emr

I have a folder in S3 and the total size of data with in the folder is more then 80 GB, I am taking this as my input in my spark sql but I am using only a few column from the imported folder data. In this case spark is reading entire 80 GB in memory. I am creating a separate dataframe to hold the filtered data that is of around 700 MB. Can someone help me to understand the working of spark either it will remove the unwanted data after filtering the required data or how can I remove that so that memory can be free for other calculation?

Comment: What is the format of files in S3?

Comment: parquet as input files